# Yii2 migrate/down error on Windows XAMPP

Tags: windows, yii2

1. Running an XAMPP machine on Windows, I tried running the command:

```
    $ ./yii migrate/down
    Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.15.1)

    Total 1 migration to be reverted:
            m180614_020037_create_table_place_lang

    Revert the above migration? (yes|no) [no]:yes
    *** reverting m180614_020037_create_table_place_lang
        > drop foreign key fk_place_lang_id_place from table place_lang ... done (time: 0.067s)
        > drop index idx_place_lang_id_place on place_lang ... done (time: 0.189s)
        > drop table place_lang ... done (time: 0.135s)
    *** failed to revert m180614_020037_create_table_place_lang (time: 0.396s)


    0 from 1 migrations were reverted.

    Migration failed. The rest of the migrations are canceled.
```

2. I ran the migration below

   ```
   use yii\db\Migration;

   // Class m180614_020037_create_table_place_lang
   class m180614_020037_create_table_place_lang extends Migration
   {
       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
       public function up()
       {
           $this->createTable('place_lang', [
               'id' => $this->primaryKey()->unsigned(),
               'place_id' => $this->integer(11)->unsigned()->notNull(),
               'locality' => $this->string(45)->notNull(),
               'country' => $this->string(45)->notNull(),
               'lang' => $this->string(2)->notNull()
           ]);

       $this->createIndex(
           'idx_place_lang_id_place',
           'place_lang',
           'place_id'
       );

       $this->addForeignKey(
           'fk_place_lang_id_place',
           'place_lang',
           'place_id',
           'place',
           'id'
       );


   }

   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public function down()
   {
       $this->dropForeignKey('fk_place_lang_id_place', 'place_lang');
       $this->dropIndex('idx_place_lang_id_place', 'place_lang');
       $this->dropTable('place_lang');

       return false;
   }


   }
   ```

   The database table was dropped, but the migration failed and I could not progress down the migration stack.

There was another migration seen here below it in the stack:

```
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;

/**
 * Class m180614_015652_create_table_place
 */
class m180614_015652_create_table_place extends Migration
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function up()
    {
        $this->createTable('place', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey()->unsigned()->notNull(),
            'place_id' => $this->string(45)->notNull(),
            'lat' => $this->string(45)->notNull(),
            'lng' => $this->string(45)->notNull(),
            'country_code' => $this->string(2)->notNull(),
            'is_country' => $this->tinyInteger(4)->notNull()
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropTable('place');

        return false;
    }

}
```

Is this a limitation of yii 2 on Windows and XAMPP or just a newbie error using the framework?

Comment: Also, when I run ./yii migrate/fresh everything works as expected

Comment: you **returned false** in down(), so migration assumes it has failed. Remove `return false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning `false` in migration marks it as failed, so this is the reason. This is documented:

> Not all migrations are reversible. For example, if the `up()` method deletes a row of a table, you may not be able to recover this row in the `down()` method. Sometimes, you may be just too lazy to implement the `down()`, because it is not very common to revert database migrations. In this case, you should return `false` in the `down()` method to indicate that the migration is not reversible.

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-migrations

You should probably not return anything if you don't want to control migrations flow.

---

`./yii migrate/refresh` works because it does not use `down()`. This command removes every table from database and runs `migrate/up`.